# Issue with bucket sort for strings C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bucket-sort

I am writing a program that takes in data for student info with a student ID # field, student first name field and student last name field. The user will input the data for each student (up to 20 students) or until the user enters '999' for the student ID field. Next I would like to sort the student info into two separate buckets based on the last name field.

I am having an issue with the buckets separating correctly. I will use the CompareTo method to compare the last name strings for the student last name array but when I print the buckets they are mixed up. For example, the last names starting with A-K should go into a 'low values' bucket and last names starting with J-Z should go into a 'high values' bucket.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace _123_Assignment2
    {
    using System;
    using static System.Console;
    class Program
    {
    struct student
    {
        public int studentId;
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student[] studentInfo = new student[20];
        string[] bucketLow = new string[20];
        string[] bucketHigh = new string [20];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 1;



        WriteLine("Enter student ID number:");
        studentInfo[x].studentId = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        while (studentInfo[x].studentId != 999)
        {
            WriteLine("Enter first name:");
            studentInfo[x].firstName = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("Enter last name:");
            studentInfo[x].lastName = ReadLine();
            x++;
            WriteLine("Enter student ID number:");
            studentInfo[x].studentId = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        }


        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {

      if(studentInfo[j].lastName.CompareTo(studentInfo[z].lastName)<= 0)

                bucketLow[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
            else
                bucketHigh[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;

                y++;
                z++;
        }

        WriteLine("Unsorted Table:");
        for (int j = 0; j < studentInfo.Length; j++)
        {

       WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}",studentInfo[j].studentId,studentInfo[j].firstName,
       studentInfo[j].lastName);
        }
        WriteLine("Bucket 1:");
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            WriteLine(bucketLow[j]);
        }
        WriteLine("Bucket 2:");
       for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            WriteLine(bucketHigh[j]);
       }
    }
}
```

}

I believe I am not writing the CompareTo method correctly, I tried sorting from both the beginning and end of the array respectively and keep getting the same results?

Comment: Along with the good suggestions in the answers. Have you considered making `student` a class and using a list instead of an array? This may make things easier.

Comment: It needs to use a structure with three arrays

Comment: If that is the case then you should trace the code where you are separating the names into the buckets. Using the same index 'y' for both buckets will create gaps in both buckets. You will need two indexes, one for the low bucket and one for the high bucket.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting gaps in the output and created two indexes to eliminate that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you sorting works (the j and z comparisons):

```
studentInfo[j].lastName.CompareTo(studentInfo[z].lastName)<= 0
```

Try to simplify your bucket sort - if you know that your buckets are A-K and J-Z maybe you should replace the part of:

```
for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
{
  if(studentInfo[j].lastName.CompareTo(studentInfo[z].lastName)<= 0)
      bucketLow[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
   else
      bucketHigh[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
      y++;
      z++;
   }
}
```

Try something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < studentInfo.Length; i++)
{
   if (studentInfo[i].lastName[0] <= 'K')
      bucketLow[y] = studentInfo[i].lastName;
   else
      bucketHigh[y] = studentInfo[i].lastName;

   y++;
}
```

(And of course add some check that you have a valid input of at least 1 character and so on...)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that I could compare to a set character like that. This is what I was looking for, it got me on the right track and giving me the output I wanted now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As this appears to be homework, I'll refrain from actually writing the correct code for you. But here are at least some of your problems:

1. Directly addressing your concern, the code you have to sort the array elements is using the wrong comparison. If you have two buckets, and you want one to represent last names starting with `A` through `K` and the other to represent last names starting with `L` through `Z`, then you need to compare to `K` or `L` to determine the right bucket. Comparing to other names is just going to randomize the data. Something like `string.Compare(studentInfo[j].lastName, "L", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0` should work.
2. You need to maintain two indexes, one for each bucket, and only increment an index for that bucket if you've actually copied a student record to that bucket.
3. Your current code will crash with an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you actually try to entry data for 20 students, because you increment `x` and store the ID value into the array without checking to see if you've entered 20 student's worth of data yet. After 20 students have been entered, then even if the user enters `999`, the `while` condition won't check that until it's too late and the code has already tried to stored the value into the array.

There may be other problems; those are the ones that I noticed at first glance.

For future reference, you should make sure when asking questions here on Stack Overflow that you provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You came close; at least the code was complete. But don't make other SO users enter your test data. Write a separate program that includes all the data built-in, doesn't have user prompts, and doesn't do *anything* that isn't strictly required to reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will implement your suggestions I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a struct and arrays then you may consider the code below for separating the names into the appropriate buckets. As I commented you need to two indexes, one for each bucket. Because you are fixing the array sizes to 20, there will be empty rows when outputting the results if there are less than 20.

```
x = studentInfo.Length;
int lowIndex = 0;
int highIndex = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
  if (String.CompareOrdinal(studentInfo[j].lastName, "L") < 0) {
    bucketLow[lowIndex] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
    lowIndex++;
  } else {
    bucketHigh[highIndex] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
    highIndex++;
  }
}
```